# Dictionary as an Enum

Tags: c#, xsd, enumeration

The [BasicTypes.xsd](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/basicTypes.xsd) from the GML schema includes the following:

```xml
<simpleType name="SignType">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>
        gml:SignType is a convenience type with values "+" (plus) and "-" (minus).
        </documentation>
    </annotation>
    <restriction base="string">
        <enumeration value="-"/>
        <enumeration value="+"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

The code generator (sparx enterprise architect) is generating the following:

```
namespace OGC.GML.BasicTypes {
    /// <summary>
    /// gml:SignType is a convenience type with values "+" (plus) and "-" (minus).
    /// </summary>
    public enum SignType : int {
        -,
        +
    }
}
```

Ofcourse, i can't have - and + as enum keys. So my question is:

**How would i define a Dicionary object to satisfy the schema as it is? Or is there a better way?** Please give code example.

It looks like [these people are using an array](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jvnet/ogc/gml-v_3_2_0-schema/1.0.0/gml-v_3_2_0-schema-1.0.0-javadoc.jar!/net/opengis/gml/v_3_2_0/SignType.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of how to use a dictionary.  What a dictionary basically does is it maps one object to another, in this case, string to int, you can always use different types for the keys and values if you like.

```
        Dictionary<string, int> SignType = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        SignType.Add("-", 0);
        SignType.Add("+", 1);

        int plusValue = SignType["+"];
```

EDIT: I've updated it again

Now you can use a static class like so

```
namespace OGC.GML.BasicTypes
{
    public static class SignType
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, int> Values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        static SignType()
        {
            Values.Add("-", 0);
            Values.Add("+", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

and you'll have to type `OGC.GML.BasicTypes.SignType.Values["+"]`

Or, you can use an instance class

```
    public class SignType
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, int> Values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        public SignType()
        {
            Values.Add("-", 0);
            Values.Add("+", 1);
        }
        public int this[string s]
        {
            get { return Values[s]; }
        }
    }
}
```

which will allow `new OGC.GML.BasicTypes.SignType()["+"]'

and even if BasicTypes is a class instead of a namespace, it's still possible to put more Enums and Sub-Classes inside of it, but that might not be the ideal solution, depending on the purpose of the namespace.

Comment: Thanks, but i know how a Dictionary works. I need to know how to define it so that it meets the schema requirements. Thy way you have it, how does it work with the namespace? will i be able to go `OGC.GML.BasicTypes.SignType["+"]`?

Comment: I've updated the post that includes code that would enable `OGC.GML.BasicTypes.SignType["+"]`

Comment: Actually, i'm not sure what i need but it has to be right with the schema. Now that you show the example though, i know that won't work because there are many clases and types defined within the namespace OGC.GML.BasicTypes that need to be instantiated. So it can't be a static class. I apologize for waisting your time, but if i knew what  i was looking for i would have done it by now. I think i need someone to tell me how to define it so that it meets the schema requirements. :/... but you're right your edit code would produce `OGC.GML.BasicTypes.SignType["+"]` which i was wrong to want.

Comment: I suppose my question is simpler put: what is the C# equivalent of that schema?